# Artifactory randomly reports Bad Credentials

Tags: artifactory

I have a big problem on our jfrog artifactory repository.

I have a script to search for artifacts, and to do this I need a token.
This works fine, but randomly I get this error:

```
jf rt search --sort-by=created --sort-order=desc --limit=1 --props='artifact=codesys;pcm33=true;master=true;variant=3.5.19.60' --url=https://artifactory.deif.com/artifactory --user=ci-bsp-sw --access-token=TOKEN amc-sw
22:47:17 [Info] Searching artifacts...
22:47:17 [Error] got unexpected server response while attempting to get JFrog Artifactory version:
server response: 401 
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 401,
      "message": "Bad credentials"
    }
  ]
}
22:47:17 [Error] got unexpected server response while attempting to get JFrog Artifactory version:
server response: 401 
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 401,
      "message": "Bad credentials"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I workaround this: I simply log into the artifactory GUI, and it works again.

I have also once experienced that I could not log into the GUI, because my password was bad. Then one of my colleagues logged in, and magically I could log in again.

I'm all confused that is happening here. It is like Artifactory must be waken up once in a while.